# If the time at which a single atom decays is random, why do groups of atoms behave in predictable ways?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, radiation, probability, half-life

Why do groups of atoms decay at predictable rates even though a single atom’s decay point is completely unpredictable? I’m having trouble wrapping my head around this.

From my reading, it seems that the law of large numbers can explain this. For example, even though it is unknown where a particular coin will land, we can say with reasonable certainty that when tossing tons of coins, about half will land on heads and the other half tails.

But in the case of a coin, there seems to be physical reasons explaining **why** about half will land on tails and heads. For starters, the coin is balanced on each side and given the rest of our knowledge about nature, there is no reason to prefer one side over the other given how objects behave when thrown in the air.

If one had never seen or tossed a coin before, assuming there was nothing biasing one side, one could still guess that about half the times you land it, it will land on heads. But in the case of atoms, one cannot seem to predict this. We observe frequencies of atoms decaying and then **after the fact** determine their probabilities of decay.

The question, then, is twofold. First, **why** is the decay rate or half life of a particular group of atoms X instead of Y? What influences this if we’ve found (and apparently proved) no possible local influence of decay on a single atom?

Second, why is there a constant decay rate for these groups of atoms in the first place? Why not complete and utter chaos (I.e. pure chaos or complete indeterminism)?

Comment: [On calculating transition probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi's_golden_rule).

Comment: Decays being random [and memoryless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness) means that they will predictably behave according to an exponential distribution. This was proven long before progress was made on the question of why a particular half-life is what it is.

Comment: 'Following up on @ConnorBehan 's comment, it's unclear whether you are asking a) why the decays are memoryless, or b) why that's sufficient to yield an exponential distribution or c) something else.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @WillO C). To clarify, I am asking why there is a defined, constant, probability in the first place. And why is it the value X instead of Y? In the case of a card being drawn, or a dice being rolled, or a coin being tossed, we have antecedent physical reasons. In the case of a single atom, we do not.

Comment: are you familiar with the formalism of quantum mechanics and the Fermi Golden Rule? I'm afraid you will have to be if you want an answer for the origin of the derivation of those decay probabilities

Comment: @Barbaud Julien The question is not about the origin of the derivation of the decay probabilities. The question is why there is a decay probability in the first place..

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure that if you understand how to derive those probabilities you will understand why there is a probability... By derive, I mean prove, not calculate. Those are a direct consequence of the QM formalism. We need to know if you are familiar with it or not before answering you (although the question itself suggests you are not, I am just checking)

Comment: @BarbaudJulien to derive the probabilities you need a QCD potential which hasnt been found yet and we would need to plug in that potential into the Schrodinger Equation.

Comment: I still don't get what you're asking.   You've **stipulated** that the decay for a single atom is random, which implies **by definition** that there is a decay probability; then you've asked why, given this, there is a decay probability.   Are you asking why the decay probability is the same for one atom as it is for another?   Or why these probabilities are independent?  Or something else?

Comment: @WillO It’s not a stipulation, atleast not mine. Current physics states that the decay point for a single atom is random.  Secondly, random means unpredictable. But unpredictability does not imply a constant probability. For example, imagine a group of atoms that 95% of the time decay to half before 4 minutes but then suddenly start always decaying to half after atleast 4 minutes have gone by. The frequencies have now changed. Why do these frequencies as we observe not change?

Comment: To use the coin example, imagine I toss 10,000 coins on Tuesday and 50% of them land on heads. Suppose I then toss them on Wednesday and find out 80% of them land on heads. In the case of a coin, this seems like an unexpected scenario. But that is because if a coin is an unbiased coin, we have no reason to prefer one side over another. But in the case of an atom, what reason is there to show why one probability distribution occurs instead of another?

Comment: 1)  We usually assume the laws of physics are not time-dependent, because this is equivalent to conservation of energy, for which we have substantial evidence.  2)  Even if the decay probability for a single atom is time-dependent, the distribution of decays for a large ensemble of atoms will be (essentially) time-independent, unless the time-dependence happens in a way that is correlated across atoms (in which case we lose conservation of energy).

Comment: I suppose that may explain why a constant probability exists for an ensemble of atoms. But why one rate over another? @WillO Thank you for your comment. Do you mind also explaining why the correlation across atoms would violate conservation of energy? In the meantime, I will do further research on this

Comment: @thinkingman:  For understanding why time-invariance of physical laws is equivalent to conservation of energy, the key phrase to Google for is "Noether's theorem".

Comment: You wrote *... random means unpredictable ...* 

That may be one of the standard meanings of random in ordinary language. 

But in science, *random* has a more precise meaning drawn from the theory of probability and statistics. In particular, to say that an event (e.g. the measured outcome of an experiment) behaves *randomly* means that there is a certain probability distribution on the outcomes of that event (e.g. the set of possible values of the measurement).

Answer (score 3):

This can be answered from statistics only.Lets assume that a atom A has a probability of decaying before 1 min 10% between 1-4 min 80% and after 4 mins 10%.Since the decay of a atom A doesnt depend on the decay of another atom B the probability $P(A\cap B) = P(A)*P(B)$. If you do the multiplication for a sample with n elements you will see that the probability  of the sample to decay between 1 and 4 min is almost certain.

Comment: "Since the decay of a atom A doesnt depend on the decay of another atom B "  ---- It's not entirely clear what the OP is asking, but one reasonable interpretation is precisely that he's questioning this assumption.

Comment: The part where you say “let’s assume” is what I’m questioning. **Why** is there a defined probability for an atom decaying in the first place? And why one value instead of another? Note that we only figure out these probabilities by observing frequencies of decay of groups of atoms.

Comment: I dont think anyone can answer you that.Nuclear physics is applied QCD and because in QCD the mediating particles couple with themselves ( they have a color charge even though they are mediating the color charge of a quark) makes math super complicated.Its like a photon to have its own electric charge.

Answer (score 1):

An atom, which is initially in the state $\psi_i$, must decay into a state $\psi_f$. This is described by the transition probability  using quantum mechanics. To visualise it think of a barrier, through which a particle has to tunnel. The height and width of the barrier determines the transition probability. This answers your first question.

Your second question, why the decay rate is constant, is in fact the result of many **random** and **independent** processes. You can check this yourself.

1. Either take one dice and roll it 100 times or take $N=100$ dices and roll them once. Next, count how many times you rolled a six. With 95% probability you will count $[10, 24]$. These numbers correspond to the probabilities $[0.1, 0.24]$.
2. Next, take $N=500$  dices and roll them once. Counting the number six, you will (probability) find $[67, 100]$. This corresponds to the probabilities $[0.134, 0.2]$. Thus, the interval around $1/6=1.\bar6$ has decreased.
3. Finally, take $N=10^{23}$ dices ... I know you won't, but this is approximately the number of atoms in your radio active sample. If we take such a large sample and count how often we find the number six, we will get $\frac{10^{23}}{6} \pm 230\,982\,418\,432$ with 95% probability. If we calculate he corresponding probabilitie we get $\frac{1}{6}\pm 2.3098\cdot 10^{-12}$. Thus, although we know that rolling each dice yields a random result, we are able to predict the cumulated outcome extremely precisely.

Comment: Before knowing where the dice will land, one can reasonably guess that it will land on one of 6 values with equal probability. But before an atom decays, we don’t know this. We find this out by observing the rates for a group of atoms. There is no reason given or known to explain the the probability distribution of decay is a certain way. But there is a reason for dice being 1/6. So, what is the reason in the case of decay?

Comment: The reason is given by the first part of my answer: Each radio active element possesses different level structures and potentials. Since these define the transition probabilities we (could) know the transition probabilities -- assuming that we know how to solve the equations. However, maybe it also helps to use your argument against you. Here it comes: In my dice example I have not stated to use a six-sided dices. Furthermore, I have to stated that the dices are fair. Both are assumptions, which you implicitly accepted. ....

Comment: ... I do not claim to know how to calculate the transition probabilities using first principles. These would involve quantum field theories. However, we don't need to understand quantum chromo dynamic in its entirety to argue that the laws of physics work consistently. Instead, we use this as one of the axioms on which physics is based on. In fact, it is known since Karl Popper that it is **impossible** to prove a theory. Thus, we have to live with the facts that we will never know for sure that something is right.